# nodejs object.property undefined error on parsing json

Tags: json, node.js, express, undefined

I am using nodejs 0.10.32/33 but with either of them i am getting undefined exception on accessing the property of a json object. My test class looks like below:

```
var jvar = '{"name":"sumit","age":"33"}';
var stdata = JSON.stringify(jvar);
var sdata = JSON.parse(stdata);
console.log(sdata);
console.log(sdata.name);
```

---

and output from the above code is:

```
{"name":"sumit","age":"33"}
undefined
```

I am unable to get what I am missing here.

Comment: Why are you stringifying something which is already a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to parse the string as JSON, because its already string, so no need to use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify),  use only [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) instead, as:

```
var jvar = '{"name":"sumit","age":"33"}';
var stdata = JSON.parse(jvar);

console.log( stdata.name ); //gives sumit
```

Answer (score 0):

stringify is to convert a json object to string. not vice versa.

```
var jvar = {"name":"sumit","age":"33"};
var stdata = JSON.stringify(jvar);
var sdata = JSON.parse(stdata);
console.log(sdata);
console.log(sdata.name);
```